# sed behavior on cygwin inconsistent

Tags: windows, sed, cygwin

i have been facing an issue with a certain sed expression working on one windows system and breaking on other. The shell script is being run on cygwin, where the cygwin and sed versions are identical.

expression:

```
url=$(echo ${!1} | sed 's/{/\\\{/g'); \
```

error on the system is :

```
Error: /usr/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated `s' command
```

So when i use it by escaping the braces it works:

```
url=$(echo ${!1} | sed 's/\{/\\\{/g'); \
```

But the breaks on the other with error saying:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 11: Invalid preceding regular expression
```

Please help .. stuck with this for some time. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: What is the output of `echo ${!1}`?

Comment: The first works for me on an LFS system, Cygwin 32-bit and Cygwin 64-bit. I get the error on all three with the second. Which makes sense to me. Since you say this is a shell script, are you running the same versions of whatever shell (looks like some 'sh' descendant) you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for a substitution by `\{`

```
echo ${!1} | sed -e 's/{/\\{/g'
```

or by `\\{`

```
echo ${!1} | sed -e 's/{/\\\\{/g')
```

3 `\` and no explicit `-e` are certainly the problem.

Info: No error with your code on my cygwin (usinf a direct string in place of `${!1}`

If you escape the first `{`, sed is waiting for a number of occurence regex and an closing brace (ex: `\{1,\}`)

Comment: @Chris J.Breisch I am using sh as my shell. And yes the second sed is the issue. But real trouble is in understanding which cygwin or sed gives different results on different windows machines (only difference is 32bit vs 64bit)

Comment: @ NeronLeVelu Thanks for the workaround but my real problem is with getting different results on different windows + cygwin machines. Any suggestions on troubleshooting such portability issues?

Comment: if the sed/shell code is not correctly write (too many or missing `\` you cannot assume that the result is the same dependng on environment. Some will let the `\` be a `\` where other remove it by assuming action on next info or other behavior.